# Difference among websphere,webservices,weblogic

Tags: web-services, websphere, weblogic

Can someone please distinguish among websphere, web services, weblogic?

WMB,IIB : Websphere

AWS : Webservices

I have few Oracle application where java web services runs.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

- WebSphere - Stands for IBM WebSphere Application Server (WAS), which provides a runtime for Java Enterprise Edition applications.
- WebLogic - Short for Oracle WebLogic Server, which is again a Java EE application server developed by Oracle.
- Web Service - A standardized form of communication between multiple applications and systems, which uses open standards such as XML & SOAP.

For more information, see the following links:

- [WebSphere Application Server v9 at IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/as_ditamaps/was900_welcome_base.html)
- [Oracle WebLogic Server 12.2.1.2.0 Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/index.html)
- [Web Services Tutorial at Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webservices/)